# Image src wil not load

Tags: html, image, macos, src, textedit

I'm totally lost for adding an image with html over textedit.

```
<img src =“/Users/Conor/Desktop/image/pic.jpeg”>
```

Error Message:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND - is the message I get when I inspect the page on chrome. The textedit file and the image are in the same folder on my desktop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the path. Read up about absolute/relative URLs

Answer (score 0):

Put image to the same folder where html file located

```
<img src="picture.jpg">
```

Put image in the **images** folder in where html file located

```
<img src="images/picture.jpg">
```

If image file located in the folder one level up from the current folder

```
<img src="../picture.jpg">
```